# Cannot fetch a web site with python urllib.urlopen() or any web browser other than Shiretoko

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

Here is the URL of the site I want to fetch

https://salami.parc.com/spartag/GetRepository?friend=jmankoff&keywords=antibiotic&option=jmankoff%27s+tags

When I fetch the web site with the following code and display the contents with the following code:

```
sock = urllib.urlopen("https://salami.parc.com/spartag/GetRepository?friend=jmankoff&keywords=antibiotic&option=jmankoff's+tags")
html = sock.read()
sock.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.prettify()
```

I get the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Error message
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>
   Invalid input data
  </h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

I get the same result with urllib2 as well. Now interestingly, this URL works on only Shiretoko web browser v3.5.7. (when I say it works I mean that it brings me the right page). When I feed this URL into Firefox 3.0.15 or Konqueror v4.2.2. I get exactly the same error page (with "Invalid input data"). I don't have any idea what creates this difference and how I can fetch this page using Python. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you see the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) doc, it says

```
urllib2.build_opener([handler, ...])¶

    .....
    If the Python installation has SSL support (i.e., if the ssl module can be imported), HTTPSHandler will also be added. 

    .....
```

you can try using urllib2 together with [ssl](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ssl.html) module. alternatively, you can use [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you get when you click on the link with a webbrowser. Maybe you are supposed to be logged in or have a cookie set or something

I get the same message for firefox 3.5.8 (shiretoko) on linux